# How can I duplicate and position the same prefab as childs for many other objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first two I positioned and rotated manually.

[image: Shield]

I added manually the DoorShieldFXLocked Variant to each Door_Left and Door_Right as child and positioned and rotated the shields to be right over the Door_Left and Door_Right.

But I have about 30 Door_Left and Door_Right objects I want to add the shield to them as childs position and rotation. Is there a way to do it automatic ? I don't want to duplicate or create the root of each door left and right Wall_Door_Long_01 but to do add the shield to each door left and door right.

Comment: Not of the parent object is no prefab .. if it was it would have been added automatically ;) Now you could use a script for it to automate it or do it one by one ;)

Comment: You could build an editor script to iterate through all of your Door_Left and Door_Right gameobjects, storing their position/rotation/scale/parentTransform to a list. Then using the script to mass delete them and instantiating a bunch of prefabs in their place, restoring the stored position/rotation/scale.